# Form validation in core php with oops concept

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns, validation

Here, i build one form validation script in php using understanding `SOLID` concept.

My question is the way i coded my code is true way for `OO` concept ?
Use of abstract class and the extend it, is that true way ?
can i strongly use interface for this functionality ?

i use `namespace` but i can't include using `use` keyword and the `filenamespace\classname`. can i have must be `include` or `require` function call with relative filename of class and then call `use` keyword.

form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP VALIDATION</title>



    <?php

        $txt_name = '';
        $txt_email = '';
        $txt_number = '';
        $txt_password = '';
        $txt_password2 = '';

        // require validation class
        require_once 'validate/validationClass.php';
        $validae = new Validation();

        $submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit');
        $server_request = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD');

        if (NULL !== $submit && $submit == "SUBMIT"):

            $validae->validate();

            $txt_name = $validae->valid('txt_name','Username','trim|required');
            $txt_email = $validae->valid('txt_email','Email','trim|required|email');
            $txt_number = $validae->valid('txt_number','Number','trim|required|numeric|min_length[9]');
            $txt_password = $validae->valid('txt_password','Password','trim|required');
            $txt_password2 = $validae->valid('txt_password2','Re Enter Password','trim|required|equalTo[txt_password]','','Password');

            // form is valid
            if($validae->is_valid()===1):
                echo "form submitted";
            endif;
        endif;
        ?>

        <style>
            #form-add input, #form-add textarea, #form-add span{display:block;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" id="form-add">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txt_name" value="<?php echo $txt_name?>"/>
            <span><?php echo $validae->error('error_txt_name');?></span>

            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txt_email" value="<?php echo $txt_email?>"/>
            <span><?php echo $validae->error('error_txt_email');?></span>

            <label>Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txt_number" value="<?php echo $txt_number?>"/>
            <span><?php echo $validae->error('error_txt_number');?></span>

            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txt_password" value="<?php echo $txt_password?>"/>
            <span><?php echo $validae->error('error_txt_password');?></span>

            <label>Re Enter Password:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txt_password2" value="<?php echo $txt_password2?>"/>
            <span><?php echo $validae->error('error_txt_password2');?></span>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

//validationAbstract.php

<?php

// namespace FormValid\Validate;

/**
 * ValidateAbstract
 * 
 * Validation Abstract Class 
 *
 * @package     formvalid
 * @subpackage  validate
 * @category    Validation
 * @author  Himanshu G Kubavat
 * @link        https://himanshukubavat.wordpress.com/
 * 
 * @access inherited
 */
abstract class ValidateAbstract {

    /**
     * required
     * 
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function required($value) {
        $val = trim($value);
        return (empty($val)) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    /**
     * numeric
     * 
     * @param int $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function numeric($value) {
        return !(empty($value)) ? (preg_match("/^([0-9]*)$/", $value)) ? 1 : 0 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * email
     * 
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function email($value) {
        return !(empty($value)) ? (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? 1 : 0 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * alphabetic
     * 
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function alphabetic($value) {
        return !(empty($value)) ? (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $value)) ? 1 : 0 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * alphanumeric
     * 
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function alphanumeric($value) {
        return !(empty($value)) ? (preg_match("/^[-_a-zA-Z0-9. ]*$/", $value)) ? 1 : 0 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * url
     * 
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function url($value) {
        return !(empty($value)) ? (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) ? 1 : 0 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * phone
     * 
     * @param int $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function phone($value) {
        return !(empty($value)) ? (preg_match("/^\+?[0-9\-]+\*?$/", $value)) ? 1 : 0 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * date
     * 
     * @param date $value
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function date($value) {
        $val = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($value));
        return ($val == "1970-01-01" || $val == "0000-00-00") ? 0 : 1;
    }

    /**
     * equalTo
     * 
     * @param mixed $value1
     * @param mixed $value2
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function equalTo($value1, $value2) {
        return !(empty($value1)) ? ($value1 == $value2) ? 1 : 0 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * min_length
     * 
     * @param int $value1
     * @param int $value2
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function min_length($value1, $value2) {
        return !(empty($value1)) ? (strlen($value1) <= $value2) ? 1 : 0 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * max_length
     * 
     * @param int $value1
     * @param int $value2
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function max_length($value1, $value2) {
        return !(empty($value1)) ? (strlen($value1) >= $value2) ? 1 : 0 : 0;
    }

}
?>

//validationClass.php
<?php

// namespace FormValid\Validate;

/**
 * Validation Class 
 *
 * @package     formvalid
 * @subpackage  validate
 * @category    Validation
 * @author  Himanshu G Kubavat
 * @link        https://himanshukubavat.wordpress.com/
 */

// use FormValid\Validate\ValidateAbstract as  ValidateAbstract;
require_once __DIR__.'/validationAbstract.php';

class Validation extends ValidateAbstract {

    private $error = array();
    private $formdata = array();
    private $form_is_valid = 1;

    public function _construct() {

    }

    public function validate() {
        $this->formdata = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    }

    public function valid($name, $label, $valid_type, $custom_msg = NULL, $same_as_control_name=NULL) {
        $validation_type = explode('|', rtrim($valid_type, '|'));
        foreach ($validation_type as $validate):
            if ($validate == "trim"):
                $val = trim($this->formdata[$name]);
            else:
                $is_true = $this->call_validation($validate, $this->formdata[$name]);
                if ($is_true === 1):
                    $val = $this->formdata[$name];
                elseif ($is_true === 2):
                    $this->set_error($name, "Validation Method Not Exists");
                else:
                    if (strpos($validate, '[') !== false):
                        $expMethod = explode('[', $validate,2);
                        $validate = $expMethod[0];
                        $arg2 = str_replace(']', '', $expMethod[1]);
                        if (method_exists($this, $validate)):
                                if($validate=="equalTo"):
                                    $msg = $this->set_message($validate, $name, $label, $same_as_control_name, $custom_msg);
                                    $this->set_error($name, $msg);
                                else:
                                    $msg = $this->set_message($validate, $name, $label, $arg2, $custom_msg);
                                    $this->set_error($name, $msg);
                                endif;

                        endif;
                    else:
                        $msg = $this->set_message($validate, $name, $label, $this->formdata[$name], $custom_msg);
                        $this->set_error($name, $msg);
                        $val = $this->formdata[$name];
                    endif;

                endif;
            endif;
        endforeach;
        return $val;
    }

    private function call_validation($function_name, $value) {
        $respone = 2;
        if (method_exists($this, $function_name)):
            $respone = $this->$function_name($value);
        else:
            if (strpos($function_name, '[') !== false):
                $expMethod = explode('[', $function_name,2);
                $function_name = $expMethod[0];
                $arg2 = str_replace(']', '', $expMethod[1]);
                if (method_exists($this, $function_name)):
                    if($function_name=="equalTo"):
                        $respone = $this->$function_name($value,$this->formdata[$arg2],$value);
                    else:
                        $respone = $this->$function_name($value,$arg2);
                    endif;

                endif;
            endif;
        endif;
        return $respone;
    }

    private function set_message($method_name, $name, $label, $val, $message = NULL) {
        if (empty($message)):
            if (empty($label)):
                return "{$name} " . $this->method_msg($method_name, $val);
            else:
                return "{$label} " . $this->method_msg($method_name, $val);
            endif;
        else:
            return $message;
        endif;
    }

    private function method_msg($method_name, $val = NULL) {
        switch ($method_name) :
            case "numeric": $msg = "is must be in numeric";
                break;
            case "email": $msg = "not valid!";
                break;
            case "alphabetic": $msg = "only alphabets!";
                break;
            case "alphanumeric": $msg = "only alpha numeric!";
                break;
            case "url": $msg = "not valid url";
                break;
            case "phone": $msg = "not valid phone";
                break;
            case "date": $msg = "not valid date";
                break;
            case "equalTo": $msg = "same as $val!";
                break;
            case "min_length": $msg = "minimum characters $val";
                break;
            case "max_length": $msg = "maximum characters $val";
                break;
            default:
                $msg = "is must be required!";
                break;
        endswitch;
        return $msg;
    }

    private function set_error($name, $message) {
        $this->form_is_valid = 0;
        $this->error["error_" . $name] = $message;
    }

    public function is_valid() {
        return $this->form_is_valid;
    }

    public function error($error_control) {
        if (isset($this->error[$error_control]) && !empty($this->error[$error_control])):
            return $this->error[$error_control];
        else:
            return '';
        endif;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Security: XSS**

All your fields are vulnerable to XSS, eg via this payload:

```
" autofocus onfocus="alert(1)
```

**Structure**

> Use of abstract class and the extend it, is that true way ?

Not really. When you extend a class, you generally want to express that it is a type of that class. For example, you may have an `Animal` abstract class, and a `Cat` class which extends it, because a Cat `is-a` Animal.

You on the other hand have a `Validation` class, which isn't a type of `ValidateAbstract`. `ValidateAbstract` contains basic validation functions, and `Validation` applies these functions, and also parses your validation codes. It's not so bad, but it isn't how inheritance is generally used.

If you wanted to use OOP, you may have a `Validator` interface, which is implemented by an `EmailValidator`, a `PhoneValidator`, etc. But that is probably going to be overkill (except if you have more complex validation to do).

**Usage**

Your validator shouldn't care where the stuff it validates comes from. But you hardcoded POST into it. Instead, pass the values that need validating on to it.

**Comments**

Proper documentation is great, but your comments look auto-generated. They do not add any actual value.

Instead, you could for example document what phone numbers may look like (it's not like there is a widely accepted standard), how email addresses are verified, how dates may look, and so on.

**Misc**

- Why are `-_.` alphanummeric?
- you say that your functions return a boolean, but they actually don't. In PHP, `1` and `0` are not equal to `true` and `false`; for example, `false == array()` but `0 != array()`, `0 == "string"` but `false != "string"`, etc.
- I don't like using the ternary operator like this in PHP, because [it doesn't work like it does in any other language](http://phpsadness.com/sad/30). It's just difficult to read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll definitely take up your advice :) really appreciate it. but can you explain me on namespace. I think! so overall i don't do anything related to oo and validation!. ; (. can i do validation in core php any other way ?